# I need to write the following block of code using Java Stream. Can someone please help me out? I'm not familiar with java streams

Tags: java, for-loop, java-stream

The code below basically ignores the string "header". I need to write the same code using java stream

```
List<String> dataitem1=new ArrayList<>();
dataitem1.add("header");
dataitem1.add("B");
dataitem1.add("C");
List<String> dataitem2=new ArrayList<>();
dataitem2.add("header");
dataitem2.add("B");
dataitem2.add("C");
List<List<String>> data=Arrays.asList(dataitem1,dataitem2);
String x=null;
for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
    for(int j=0;j<data.get(i).size();j++){
                if((i==0 && j==0) || data.get(i).get(j).equals(x)){
                    x=data.get(i).get(j);
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println(data.get(i).get(j));
            }
}
```

Comment: Corrected my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `filter` method.

```java
list.stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .filter(Predicate.not(str -> str.equals("header")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Inorder to replace the string "header" with another rather than ignoring it, you need to replace the `filter` statement with

```java
.map(str -> (str.equals("header") ? "anotherstring" : str))
```

Comment: will this work on a list of list of strings

Comment: I want to eventually store "B","C","B","C" in a List<String>

Comment: getting the error - cannot resolve method collect in predicate

Comment: @ChristianAlderson one `)` was missing. updated the answer

Comment: Accepted the answer. I have one more doubt, can you help me with that?

Comment: @ChristianAlderson If the doubt is not related with this question, then you could post it as a different question

Comment: It is related to this question only

Comment: @ChristianAlderson okay. then you could add as comment or update the question

Comment: I am ignoring the header string here. But instead of ignoring it , I would like to replace it by "myheading" so that the final output looks like "myheading" "B" "C" "myheading" "B" "C". I want to do it using java stream

Comment: @ChristianAlderson updated.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. You're a JAVA Master

Comment: @ChristianAlderson please go through https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams this article to know more about streams. Also avoid "thank you" in comment section

Comment: Can you suggest some good resources for learning Spring and Unit Testing(Mockito)?

Comment: Sure will go through the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229673/discussion-between-christian-alderson-and-gautham-m).